# What's the best way to modularize a User schema so it's generic

Tags: mongodb, database-design, schema, database-schema, database

I have a database design question. Basically I want to be able to create a schema for a User model, then use this User model in other models that extend User but I want to design it in such a way that it's generic enough to be used in every application.

For example a Profile or Account model might extend User, and in both cases they will be different based on the web application you are designing but the core credentials of User should never be different across any web application.

What fields do you think should be in the User model?

I think the bare minimum to successfully handle authentication would be:

- email (the login unique identifier)
- salt (obviously!)
- password (duh)
- lostToken (a hash to verify lost password functionality)
- role (member, admin, editor, etc.. IMO this list of roles would differ between sites however it's too important to the User model not to have here?)

Now we get into other interesting fields that are still very very useful:

- createdAt (when the account was created)
- ipAddress (track the ip when the account was created)
- refererUrl (which site it came from)
- lastLoggedIn (the last time the user logged in)
- isOnline (is the user currently online)

And even more fields that are still pretty useful:

- username (might not be used on every site)
- number of consecutive logins (similar to the stack network)

I think anything else like social data (likes, votes, profile views), badges/achievements, the last time they updated their profile/account/whatever, and other info like their name belong in the per-site Profile model.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I think youve got what you need already sorted out.  Anything else really depends on your use cases, which we dont know.

One recommendation I have is around Salt and Password - You should be using something like BCrypt which will created a salted hash for you as a single field.

Comment: It's more about abstracting the code for portability than the fields themselves. I mean, most dynamic sites will likely have some form of user auth functionality but pretty much every site will require storing different info.

The goal is to put what every site would need into user.

Comment: Ok well I dont know what kind of answer you are looking for but as I said, I think you have it figured out.  You tagged it as MongoDB - MongoDB is schemaless and is incredibly flexible.  You can store things however you want - I would think more about my query patterns to understand how I plan to fetch data.

Comment: Yep, I tagged it with mongodb but I'm also using node/express/mongoose (mongoose is a db driver for mongodb) and to take advantage of some of its magic you need to define schemas.

I ran out of tags to include every piece of tech included but wanted to keep the discussion aimed towards database schemas rather than what type of database you're using since the way to "extend" a model will be highly dependent to the db you're using but also irrelevant in this case.